# Google sheets, Countif with isdate not working

Tags: google-sheets-formula, countif

I need to count the cells that have a date in google sheets, and it's not working. It's a payment sheet so I have $ amount and date of payment. I need to now how many payments have been done, and the way we see this is if it has a date beside the $.
I've tried three versions of the formula.

I have dates and numbers in columns c:g, and need to count only the dates.
IE:
$2,000; 1/1/21;$3,000;2/1/21;$3,000;;$3,000;;
It should count two dates, but I get 0 as a result.
Here are the formulas:
`countif(E3:J3;ARRAYFORMULA(ISDATE_STRICT(E3:J3)))`
`countif(E4:J4;isdate(E4:J4))`
`countif(E5:J5;isdate())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(--ISDATE_STRICT(E3:J3)))
```

or

```
=count(filter(E3:J3,ISDATE_STRICT(E3:J3)))
```

Comment: Thank you; both worked. Yet I don't understand why mine didn't ;)